# How to SELECT something with different WHERE statement from the others

Tags: sql, pivot

What I'm trying to do is:

I make a pivot table in SQL where I create a few columns with user accounts, summing amount per date, etc. Those columns will all have the same WHERE conditions.

However, I want to create another column with amount for last 30 days which will be with condition `WHERE date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30`.

How do I create a selection in the same table with its own different condition?

For example:

I have this:

[image: This]

I want to make a pivot table like this

[image: That]

I have already made everything except the last column - it needs to sum the amount with condition `WHERE date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30`.

My other columns will have condition `WHERE date >= '20200201'`

I have already defined the days in the pivot table as days of the current month while this last column needs to include everything from the last 30 days, so not only in the current month.

How do I make the selection where column "Total for last 30 days" has its own conditions, different from the other columns?

Comment: What is your database ? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: And also the expected result. [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I edited the post to include what I have and what my problem is.

Comment: Great but still missing the database. Is it Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Date functions differ by databases, but here is the idea:

```
select user,
       sum(case when extract(day from date) = 1 then amount end) as day_1,
       sum(case when extract(day from date) = 2 then amount end) as day_2,
       sum(case when extract(day from date) = 3 then amount end) as day_3,
       sum(case when extract(year from date) = extract(year from current_date) and
                     extract(month from date) = extract(month from current_date)
                then amount
           end) as month_total,
       sum(case when date >= current_date - interval '30 da' then amount end) as last_30_days
from t
group by user;
```

The exact functions depend on the database you are using.